# Console prompt in bash changed unexpectedly

Tags: bash, console, command-line

In `bash`, my default console prompt looked like this:

```
kit:~ Kit$
```

I do not know what I did to make it change to this:

```
112:~ Kit$
```

What caused the `112:` to appear? I'm in a different network, where my computer has an IP address that begins with `112.`. Is it because of that? Or something else?

Comment: Is it really part of the prompt? Isn't it just a last line printed from the previous command without a line end? As in `echo -n 112:`

Comment: What's the output of `hostname`?

Answer (score 1):

The bash prompt is governed by the `PS1` variable and it's hard to say what's going on without knowing what the variable is set to.

`echo "$PS1"` will show you its current value.

For more information type `man bash` and look under `PROMPTING` section.

Comment: He's on the same system, but on a different network (e.g. carried his laptop somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it changed, but why not change it back? - [look at this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Has this happened before, or is it an isolated incident? If it hasn't happened before, just change it back.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to change it back to the way it was. To change it back, add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1='\w \u\$ '
```